# Qt Animation: Appearing & Disappearing Objects

Tags: user-interface, qt, animation, qt4

I'm writing a video annotation application with Qt4 in which users need to be able to seek to various points in a video, putting markers on various objects and then setting keypoints for those markers so that they stay on the objects in the video as they move around.  QGraphicsItemAnimation seems like a great place to start for these markers, however they need to be able to appear and disappear at specific times, which I can't figure out how to do with the QGraphicsItemAnimation. I could set the scale at 0 to make the objects disappear, but that seems like a pretty hacky solution, and I'm guessing that the paint engine would still waste cpu cycles trying to draw those invisible objects.  Does anyone have a better solution than this? I'm using Qt 4.5.3 right now, but I'm willing to upgrade to 4.6 if it makes things easier.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the functionality you want of showing/hiding `QGraphicsItem` objects is beyond the scope of the simple ["tweening"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening) that the animation class performs.  It is only for one object at a time, and any appearance or disappearance you have to write yourself.

You still *might* get some mileage out of `QGraphicsItemAnimation` (although the fact that it uses its own timer instead of being locked to the frame clock of your video is a little dodgy).

Neglecting "seeking" for a moment, there is a [QTimeLine::finished()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qtimeline.html#finished) signal.  If you let the end of an annotation's active animation timeline represent the point where you want it to disappear, you can trigger [QGraphicsItem::hide()](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#hide) at that point.  When it comes time to turn it back on, you would construct a new `QGraphicsItemAnimation` (based on the next run of keyframe data for that object) and call [QGraphicsItem::show()](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#show).

Note that one of the headlining features of Qt 4.6 is the [QtAnimation](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html) framework, which is more sophisticated but also rather complex.  I've not used it yet, but [looking over the examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qwidget.html#visible-prop) it seems like you might be able to "animate" a visibility or opacity property.